# Insert a chart in excel sheet through Matlab

Tags: matlab, com, charts, excel, vba

I am trying to insert a chart in a excel sheet. I am using the following code to insert the chart which is working.

```
Charts = Workbook.Charts;
Chart = invoke(Charts,'Add');

try
    Excel.ActiveChart.Name = chart_title;
catch e
    errordlg(e.message);
    invoke(Excel,'Quit');        
    error(['Sheet (' chart_title ') already exists!']);        
end
```

However, this will create a new sheet for the chart with data from all the columns. But, I would like to create a chart ( does not matter if it is a new sheet) but only with a selected column, say something like `B2:B16` ( use only selected column)

Any idea, how to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's relatively simple. I was able to get all the information I needed from [the Microsoft Office Excel document page.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fzyhc74.aspx)

Here's all the commands I used.

```
% Open up the active server and get a workbook
Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
Workbook = Excel.workbooks.Open('d:\Temp\test.xlsx');
% Add a chart to the workbook
Chart = invoke(Workbook.Charts,'Add');
% Specify the range for the chart
invoke(Chart, 'SetSourceData', Excel.Range('Sheet1!$B$2:$B$16'));
% Make excel visible
Excel.Visible = true;
```